Get raw memo without length prefix
I am sending a tx with a memo using getAddMemoInstruction({ memo: "<uuid>" }) from @solana-program/memo. When I use rpc.getSignaturesForAddress(...), the memo is returned as a string prefixed with its length in square brackets. For example:
{
  blockTime: 1727333239n,
  confirmationStatus: 'finalized',
  err: null,
  memo: '[36] 019227ea-86ef-77da-b472-ed9198401d38',
  signature: '5vgBFBDH2BovUe2SNk575TpMRqvEeveK2djnrNbCuPFxUSsYxzEEdFYxgBFmhYdprqpVU2DQGgL5amAFjP6GjzgL',
  slot: 328653916n
}

There is no prefix in the original memo, and there is no prefix in the memo when I look up the tx in Solana Explorer, so I suppose it's added by RPC. But what is the reason for using the prefix? I mean, the string itself has a length, why injecting its length literally within the string?
Am I supposed to strip the prefix with regexp and call it a day? It is safe to rely that it will always be there, or is it some configurable RPC setting?

If we go to the rpc crate that Anza provides (which is what I'm guessing most RPC providers just directly use out of the box), we can see it uses transaction-status internally. If we check transaction-status, we can see for each type of transaction it implements a trait called ExtractMemo which is what's used to read the memo of a given transaction.
If we check a little deeper, we can see for all transaction types at the moment, this gets mapped to an internal function called extract_and_fmt_memo_data, which is defined as:
fn extract_and_fmt_memo_data(data: &[u8]) -> String {
    let memo_len = data.len();
    let parsed_memo = parse_memo_data(data).unwrap_or_else(|_| "(unparseable)".to_string());
    format!("[{memo_len}] {parsed_memo}")
}

That's where the length is coming from, so although it's not officially specified in the spec (although it should be!), the probability of it being there is quite high since I don't see a reason why an rpc operator would choose to edit this specific function.
